# Bootstrap: when navbar collapsed branding overlapping other objects

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

When the navbar collapses into the burger menu, the branding overlaps with the navigation links - how do I separate them to avoid this happening? Ideally I'd like the branding to appear at the top.

The navbar structure is correct and working as expected when not collapsed, with all items positioned correctly, the problem only occurs when the menu collapses.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/PeterLawson/Lkv8gj9a/2/

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!---Style Sheets-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!---Website Title-->
  <title>Notepad</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!---Main Content-->
  <!---Navigation Bar-->
  <nav class="navbar nav-fill navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light ">
    <div class="container">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMenu">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarMenu">
        <!---Search Bar-->
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
        <!---Notepad Branding-->
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
          <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images\notepad-logo2.png" alt="Notepad Logo"
                style="width:150px;"></a></li>
        </ul>
        <!---Navigation Links-->
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Discover Notepads</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarProductDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
              aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Catalogue
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarProductDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Furniture</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Lighting</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Decor</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <!---User Profile-->
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarAvatarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
              aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              <img src="images\man.png" class="avatar">
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarAvatarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">My Notepads</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Create New Notepad</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign Out</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!---Bootstrap JavaScript and jQuery-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!---Firebase SDK-->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.5/firebase-app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-nav.navbar-center {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translatex(-50%);
}

.navbar { 
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.main-logo{
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px; 
}

.navbar-nav li a {
    line-height: 50px;
   }

.dropdown-menu > li > a { 
    height: 50px; 
}

.avatar {
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow:
      inset 0 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.6), 
      0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    background-color: transparent !important;
    z-index: 999;
  }

  .avatar img {
    border-radius: inherit;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 998;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest solution will be to take the brandImage out of the navigation - that'll help you achieve what you want; your `styles.css` file wasn't referred to completely, so i inserted a different logo - based on your logo, you would have to tune the padding etc.

Working **snippet** below:

```css
.navbar-nav.navbar-center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translatex(-50%);
}

.navbar {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.main-logo {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
}

.navbar-nav li a {
  line-height: 50px;
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a {
  height: 50px;
}

.avatar {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background-color: transparent !important;
  z-index: 999;
}

.avatar img {
  border-radius: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 998;
}

.navBarBrand {
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 21px);
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

@media screen AND (min-width:991px) {
  .navBarBrand {
    padding: 12px 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!---Website Title-->

<!---Main Content-->
<ul class="navBarBrand">
  <li>
    <a class="=" href="#"><img src="https://www.akberiqbal.com/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png" alt="Notepad Logo"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
<!---Navigation Bar-->
<nav class="navbar nav-fill navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light ">
  <div class="container">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMenu">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarMenu">
      <!---Search Bar-->
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
      <!---Notepad Branding-->

      <!---Navigation Links-->
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Discover Notepads</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarProductDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Catalogue
            </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarProductDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Furniture</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Lighting</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Decor</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <!---User Profile-->
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarAvatarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <img src="images\man.png" class="avatar">
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarAvatarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">My Notepads</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Create New Notepad</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign Out</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<!---Bootstrap JavaScript and jQuery-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!---Firebase SDK-->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.5/firebase-app.js"></script>
```

Comment: Perfect - this is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you.